# Unable to create an ASP.Net empty web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm trying to learn developing ASP.Net web applications, therefore I started from the basic. I tried to create an empty Web Application from VS 2013 Ultimate. Since then I'm getting this following error.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: IIS Error]

Comment: Did you install IIS?

Comment: @AVD Yes i did. But just checked in the "Turn on the features" box within Control Panel, the IIS was un ticked. So i'll restart the machine and see whether it works. Thanks.

Comment: follow the link to reset the applicationhost.config file, in case it got corrupted..

Comment: @Dreamweaver How should the applicationhost.config file should like? The error says on line number 22 which has this line in the file:
  <site name="todolist_Service(1)" id="2">

Comment: iIS Express is not IIS, make sure you are looking at the correct host config file - it will be somewhere in the Documents/IIS Express folder of the profile you are logged in as.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yep I'm looking at the correct file. (Users/mine/Documents/IISExpress/config)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the config file is correct or not, how could i check?

Comment: I reinstalled the IIS express, and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<section>` tags are missing in the applicationhost.config file. You could try to delete all website blocks in that file and then create a new empty web project.

Also there seems to be something wrong with the path because you have a ? in your path to the filename.
I don't know if the path will change when you have a working project.